# Merge mutiple rows into single row with json column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to merge the rows into a single row with JSON column in SQL Server

Source table:

| id | studyid | eye | measurements | subjectref | type | source | dateOn |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1s | left | {"a":1,"b":2} | 1reference | k | abc | 10/12/2022 |  |
| 2 | 1s | left | {"c":"1a"} | 1reference | o | abc | 10/12/2022 |  |
| 3 | 1s | left | {"d":2} | 1reference | or | abc | 10/12/2022 |  |
| 4 | 2s | left | {"a":1,"b":2} | 1reference | k | abc | 01/11/2022 |  |

Desired output:

| studyId | eye | measurements | subjectref | source | dateOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1s | left | {"a":1,"b":2,"c":"1a","d":2} | 1reference | abc | 10/12/2022 |
| 2s | left | {"a":1,"b:2"} | 1reference | abc | 01/11/2022 |

Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as discussed in your deleted previous question) the JSON is simple as shown and there is no possibility of needing to merge different rows having the same key you can just do this with string concatenation. [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FlsGDIhz)

The `TRIM` removes the opening and closing braces, from each `measurements` document. The ones in each group get concatenated together with a comma and then opening and closing braces are appended onto the result.

```
SELECT   studyId,
         eye,
         measurements = '{' + STRING_AGG(TRIM('{}' FROM measurements), ',') + '}',
         subjectRef,
         source,
         dateOn
FROM     YourTable
GROUP BY studyId,
         eye,
         subjectRef,
         source,
         dateOn
```

Comment: Thanks Smith. Can you please share any reference/idea that if possibility of same key is there in  multiple rows having same json key, expected result is we can override the key any of the row json property value of the same key.